# .ccproj wouldn't build for no apparent reason

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, cloud

I'm playing with a Azure sample [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg433178). After some (rather non-damaging IMO) manipulations the project will no longer build - when I hit "Build" the following appears in output:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: CloudService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\Temp\AzureAdvancedRolesSource\Ex2-StartupTasks\CS\Begin\CloudService\CloudService.ccproj" (entry point):

.... many, many more lines with nothing looking like an error, then

Task "Message"
    Start - PackageComputeService
Task "Message"
    ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir is C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\
Task "Message"
    EnableIntelliTrace is false
Task "Message"
    SiteMapping: Web:SampleWebApp -> C:\Temp\AzureAdvancedRolesSource\Ex2-StartupTasks\CS\Begin\SampleWebApp\
Task "Message"
    ModelFile            is 
Task "Message"
    OutputDirectory      is bin\Debug\CloudService.csx\
Task "Message"
    PackRoles            is C:\Temp\AzureAdvancedRolesSource\Ex2-StartupTasks\CS\Begin\CloudService\obj\Debug\SampleWebApp\, Name=SampleWebApp, EntryPoint=SampleWebApp.dll, SourceDir=C:\Temp\AzureAdvancedRolesSource\Ex2-StartupTasks\CS\Begin\SampleWebApp\
Task "Message"
    RoleProperties       is SampleWebApp, EntryPoint=SampleWebApp.dll, TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0
Task "Message"
    ServiceDefinitionCopy is ServiceDefinition.build.csdef
Task "Message"
    ServiceConfigurationCopy is bin\Debug\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
Task "Message"
    Calling ServicePack
Task "CSPack"
Done building project "CloudService.ccproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

I guess there's something wrong with `CSPack`. How do I find out what's wrong and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That turned out to be some unreproduceable problem with CSPack which I resolved by deleting all the stuff in the "cloud solution" directory (`C:\Temp\AzureAdvancedRolesSource\Ex2-StartupTasks\CS\Begin\CloudService\` in the sample) except the very files that were there initially.

Comment: Hey, your link in the original post is dead.  What are you referring to with the "cloud solution directory?"  I have the same problem as you except with a real project.

Comment: @Casey That's where .ccproj is.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to run CSPack from the commandline. This will hopefully let you see the error that CSPack is running into when you're trying to build in visual studio.

If you aren't quite sure how to run CSPack, [Steve Marx](http://blog.smarx.com) and [Ryan Dunn](http://dunnry.com) covered [how to use CSPack](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-29-Working-with-CSPack) in an episode of [Cloud Cover](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover).

Note that there is a special location for your Startup Tasks to be placed in order for the CSPack Utility to be able to execute properly, I have outlined this in my blog post "[Installing PHP on Windows Azure Leveraging Full IIS Support](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2011/02/09/Installing-PHP-on-Windows-Azure-leveraging-Full-IIS-Support-Part-1.aspx)".

Good Luck!

~Cory()

Comment: Thank you, I tried hard to use CSPack from the command line withu any success I finally just tried to clear the cloud solution folder and retry and that helped - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275437/ccproj-wouldnt-build-for-no-apparent-reason/6506542#6506542